# Using Laravel DB object to run postgresql functions with input parameters

Tags: postgresql, laravel

I have some postgresql functions that I run in the form:

`SELECT * FROM pgfunction(1,2,3);`

This enables me to filter / order / group the results:

`SELECT * FROM pgfunction(1,2,3) WHERE value > 10;`

How could I pass the parameters to the postgresql function in laravel using prepared statements in order to filter the results in laravel. Example:

```
DB::table('pgfunction',array(1,2,3))->where('value','>','10');
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

`DB::raw` will create a raw SQL string, but not use it as a query. You may need to use a `DB::select()` to run a "raw sql" query.

```
$fnc = sprintf("pgfunction(%s)", implode(',', array(1,2,3));

DB::select()->from(DB::raw($fnc))->where('value', '>', 10);
```

Note: This is untested on my end. Hope it helps. See the docs on using [Raw Expressions](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#raw-expressions) for more information on using that.

Comment: Yes, I have mixed "DB::RAW" and "DB::table". I have fixed this typo in the question. The idea was to use this function as a table exactly as postgresql does.