# How to call the postgress function/stored procedure from laravel controller?

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel

laravel code:

```
$allUsers=DB::select('call getUsersCount()');
```

errror:

```
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "call" LINE 1: call getUsersCount() ^ (SQL: call getUsersCount()) (Bindings: array ( ))
```

function in postgress:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."getUsersCount"()
      RETURNS bigint AS
    $BODY$
      SELECT count(*)  FROM users;
    $BODY$
      LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
      COST 100;
    ALTER FUNCTION public."getUsersCount"()
      OWNER TO postgres;
```

So what is the best way to call the Postgres functions from laravel?

I don't want to convert this to like table calling. it should be like a stored procedures.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Laravel DB object to run postgresql functions with input parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768637/using-laravel-db-object-to-run-postgresql-functions-with-input-parameters)

Comment: I would like call it same as mysql stored procedure. I think above one is not similar to this question

Comment: `DB::select()->from(DB::raw('getUsersCount()''))` not working?

Comment: No its giving error:  Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Database\Connection::select()

Comment: Try `DB::select(DB::raw('"getUsersCount"()'))`

Comment: this also giving same error:SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "getUsersCount" LINE 1: getUsersCount() ^ (SQL: getUsersCount()) (Bindings: array ( ))

Comment: $allUsersCount=DB::select('SELECT public."getUsersCount"()'); this is working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To call the Postgres functions from Laravel controller:

use the  following method

```
$allUsersCount=DB::select('SELECT public."getUsersCount"()');
```

Comment: nope this is not working as for laravel 5.8 and postgres 10

Answer (score 1):

To call the Postgres functions from Laravel controller:

use the following method

```
$allUsersCount=DB::select('SELECT * from public.getUsersCount()');
```